# How to check IPv6 address via command line?

Tags: linux, ip, ipv6, command-line-interface

How do I check the IPv6 address via command line?
For IPv4 I simply use:

`curl ipinfo.io/ip`

*This doesn't work for IPv6.*

Comment: Does `wget -O - v6.ident.me 2>/dev/null  && echo` work?

Comment: You do realise you don't mention an operating system in this question right?

Comment: IPinfo.io does support IPv6, but via the v6 domain - eg. curl v6.ipinfo.ip/ip

Comment: In Feb 2023: `Could not resolve host: v6.ipinfo.ip`

Comment: @DanilaVershinin: v6.ipinfo.ip has only a v6 address (necessarily) thus it will only resolve for a program that handles v6 (i.e. getaddrinfo) on a system which supports v6. What program(s) are you using, with what options, on what system(s), with what networking?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 before you comment, you should try to resolve it ;-)

Answer (score 30):

to show the localy listed ipv6 address one can use

```
ip -6 addr
```

This will show all locally configured ipv6 address including the link-local address.  to show just global reachable addresses you can use

```
ip -6 addr show scope global
```

when you use a service like `curl ipinfo.io/ip` you are most often trying to work out the nat addresses you are using to reach the internet.  Nat is much less common with IPv6 however there are many "whatsmyip" type service for ipv6 e.g.

With DNS:

```
dig -6 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com
dig -t aaaa +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

With HTTPS

```
curl -6 https://ifconfig.co
curl -6 https://ipv6.icanhazip.com
```

with telnet

```
telnet -6 ipv6.telnetmyip.com
```

Even With ssh

```
  ssh -6 sshmyip.com
```

I have seen this service over many other protocols as well so google and have fun ;)

Answer (score 4):

Ipify has a ipv6 endpoint:  `curl https://api64.ipify.org`

Answer (score 3):

ipinfo.io/ip doesn't support IPv6. You may want to try:

```
curl -6 https://ifconfig.co/ip
```

instead.

Comment: It does, but via the v6 subdomain (eg. curl v6.ipinfo.io)

Answer (score 1):

The IP tools will show IPV6 addresses:

```
ip addr | grep inet6
```

Comment: Thank, Which one to pick `scope global` or `scope link`?

Comment: Scope global is the rough equivalent of a public IP address in IPv4, while scope link is the rough equivalent of a private or APIPA address in IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the public IPv6 address you can do this with the **dig** command and then pipe the result into the **sed** command to remove the closing quotes.

```
dig -6 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | sed 's|"||g'
```

Another alternative is using the **curl** command and pulling the IP address from a URL such as OpenDNS'.

```
root@ubuntu:~# curl -s -6 "https://myipv6.p1.opendns.com/get_my_ip"
{
  "ip": "2a00:2345:dead:beef:1234:4567:89ab:cdef"
}
```

To print only the value (the IP address) you can specify the **-r** parameter.

```
root@ubuntu:~# curl -s -6 "https://myipv6.p1.opendns.com/get_my_ip" | jq -r '.ip'
2a00:2345:dead:beef:1234:4567:89ab:cdef
```

Comment: Are you sure this lookup works?

Comment: @DanielK yes I've just tested it on a Fedora server.

Answer (score 0):

`ip.sb` support both IPv4 and IPv6.
To get IPv6 adress,use:

```
curl -6 ip.sb
```

And, `curl -4 ip.sb` for IPv4 adress.

Answer (score 0):

This works for "lo" AND "eth0-X", IPv4 and IPv6, respectively:

ip -4 addr
ip -6 addr

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/575242)